# Numpad shortcuts alternatives

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm following a Tutorial that requires me to use the Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0 to adjust the camera.

On my type of Laptop Keyboard, I do not have the Numpad keys.

Is there an alternative to that shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your keybinds by going to *Edit* menu (top left) *Preferences > Keymap*. The one you're talking about is called *Align Camera to View*. Click on it and you'll be able to change the bind.

Comment: Thank you, Draco1660.